# Pandas action on column between two numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Currently using Pandas and Numpy. I have a dataframe named 'df'. Lets say I have the below data, how can I give the third column a value based on a between clause? I'd like to ***treat this as a vectorised approach*** if possible to maintain the speed of what I already have.

I've tried lambda functions, but frankly I don't understand what I'm doing and I'm getting errors such as the object has no attribute 'between'.

General approach - using a non vectorised approach:

```
NOTE: I am looking for a way to make this vectorised.

If df.['Col2'] is between 0 and 10
   df.['Col 3'] = 1
Elseif df.['Col2'] is between 10.01 and 20
   df.['Col3']  = 2
Else if df.['Col2'] is between 20.1 and 30
   df.['Col3']  = 3
```

Sample set

```
+------+------+------+
| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
+------+------+------+
| a    |    5 |    1 |
| b    |   10 |    1 |
| c    |   15 |    2 |
| d    |   20 |    2 |
| e    |   25 |    3 |
| f    |   30 |    3 |
| g    |    1 |    1 |
| h    |   11 |    2 |
| i    |   21 |    3 |
| j    |    7 |    1 |
+------+------+------+
```

Many thanks

Comment: "Sample Set" contains the example output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Solution reusing your current code:

```py
def cust_func(row):
    r = row['Col2']
    if  r >=0 AND r<=10:
        val = 1
    elif r >=10.01 AND r<=20:
        val = 2
    elseif r>=20.01 AND r<=30:
        val = 3
    return val

df['Col3'] = df.apply(cust_func, axis=1)
```

## Optimal solution:

```py
cut_labels = [1, 2, 3]
cut_bins = [0, 10, 20,30]
df['Col3'] = pd.cut(df['Col2'], bins=cut_bins, labels=cut_labels)
```

Comment: This isn't a vectorised operation though, is it? So the performance would be significantly slower on a large dataset

Comment: Thank you for the Optimal solution. That's a really cool approach - and something I didn't even know the term to search for. But, now I've extended that into my current script. My data processing time went from several minutes using the initial logic to several seconds using the optimal logic.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways: [numpy select](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) and [numpy.searchsorted](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html); I prefer the latter as I don't have to list out the conditions - it works on the bisect algorithm, as long as your data is sorted; and yes, I'd like to think it is the fastest of the bunch.

It would be cool if you ran some timings and shared the results:

```
  Col1  Col2
0   a   5
1   b   10
2   c   15
3   d   20
4   e   25
5   f   30
6   g   1
7   h   11
8   i   21
9   j   7

   #step 1: create your 'conditions'

#sort dataframe on Col2

df = df.sort_values('Col2')
#benchmarks are ur ranges within which you set your scores/grade
benchmarks = np.array([10,20,30])

#the grades to be assigned for Col2
score = np.array([1,2,3])

#and use search sorted
#it will generate the indices for where the values should be
#e.g if you have [1,4,5] then the position of 3 will be 1, since it is between 1 and 4
#and python has a zero based index notation
indices = np.searchsorted(benchmarks,df.Col2)

#create ur new column by indexing the score array with the indices
df['Col3'] = score[indices]

df = df.sort_index()

df

    Col1    Col2  Col3
0    a       5      1
1    b       10     1
2    c       15     2
3    d       20     2
4    e       25     3
5    f       30     3
6    g       1      1
7    h       11     2
8    i       21     3
9    j       7      1
```

Answer (score 1):

Please Try,Boolean select

```
a=df['Col2'].between(0,10)
b=df['Col2'].between(10.01,20)
c=df['Col2'].between(20.1,30)
```

Apply [np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
import numpy as np
df['Col3']  =np.where(a,1,(np.where(b,2,(np.where(c,3,df['Col3'] )))))
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much. I wound up using Dexters approach as I was able to avoid nesting where clauses. My actual clauses were a bit more extensive than the question implied.

Comment: Thats how it goes. Happy you found a solution and also gave me a chance to have a try by posting your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this nice and cleanly with np.select(). I added some <= because I guessed you wanted all the values updated. But it's an easy edit if needed.

```
conditions = [(df['Col2'] > 0) & (df['Col2'] <= 10),
               (df['Col2'] > 10) & (df['Col2'] <= 20),
               (df['Col2'] > 20) & (df['Col2'] <= 30) ]

updates = [1, 2, 3]

df["Col3"] = np.select(conditions, updates, default=999)
```

Using your original range would result in this, where the values == 10, 20, 30 get the value 999 from np.select().

```
conditions = [(df['Col2'] > 0) & (df['Col2'] < 10),
               (df['Col2'] > 10.01) & (df['Col2'] < 20),
               (df['Col2'] > 20.1) & (df['Col2'] < 30) ]

updates = [1, 2, 3]

df["Col3"] = np.select(conditions, updates, default=999)

print(df)

    Col1    Col2    Col3
0   a   5   1
1   b   10  999
2   c   15  2
3   d   20  999
4   e   25  3
5   f   30  999
6   g   1   1
7   h   11  2
8   i   21  3
9   j   7   1
```